# Причина происходящего, VirtualBox на Ubuntu 14.04 не запускает приложения на DeritX 9?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

Использовался VirtualBox версии 4, и версии 6.
Использовался на системе установленной, и системе DVD Live.
При этом VirtualBox использовал расширение VBOX extension pack, своей же версии, в случаях обеих, а на системе гостевой, был установлен драйвер virtualbox guest additions iso.
Ранее приложение эти использовались успешно.
Может ли это быть винда испорченной (поражённой)? переустановить возможности нет.
При запуске 3dMark06 выдаёт:
IDirect3D9::GetDeviceCaps failed: Not available (D3DErr_NOTAVAILABLE).

Comment: я так чувствую, что никогда в vbox не сделают нормальное видео, используйте лучше vmware player, он тоже бесплатный, машину можно из vbox туда экпортировать

Comment: На гостевой стоит DiretX, на хостовой установлено OpenGL:
libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1
libqt4-opengl (>= 4:4.5.3),
libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.5.3),
libqtgui4

Comment: Раньше на Live DVD установкой VirtualBox можно было запускать 3D приложения без проблем. Грешит на добавленность архитектуры i386?